# Service to Service Calls Using Client Credentials

Tags: powershell, office365api, azure-ad-graph-api

I tried to create an alias for group in office 365 using below code but it shows some error.how to solve this. I tried to use service to service calls method. I got the token generated. How to check its valid or not? Is it possible to create alias using api for group without powershell option? if no kindly advice me to for other options..

```
string clientId = "************";
string clientsecret = "******";
string tenantId = "********";
//string resourceUri = "http://office.microsoft.com/outlook/";
string redirectUri = "https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf";
var authUri = "https://login.windows.net/" + tenantId + "/oauth2/authorize/";
var RESOURCE_URL = "https://graph.windows.net";

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authUri);
var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId: clientId, clientSecret: clientsecret);
var result = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(RESOURCE_URL, credential).Result;
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "bearer " + result.AccessToken);
string content = @"{
              'displayName': 'mailgrouptest',
              'groupTypes': ['Unified'],
              'mailEnabled': true,
              'mailNickname': 'mailalias1',
              'securityEnabled': false
      }";

 var httpContent = new StringContent(content, Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"), "application/json");
 var response = client.PostAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups", httpContent).Result;
 Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
```

When i run this code in console it  shows an error like this....is the problem with  token ? or tenant id?

> ```
> {
>   "error": {
> "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
> "message": "Access token validation failure.",
> "innerError": {``
>   "request-id": "*****-***-",
>   "date": "2016-05-25T04:53:08"
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

kindly advice me to create alias for group in api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mailNickName of group is not able to update using the Microsoft Graph at present.

As a workaround, we can create a new group with the specific the mailNickName you wanted and use the new group. Here is the code to create a group with mailNicekName for your reference:

```
        string clientId = "";
        string clientsecret = "";
        string tenant = "yourdomain.onmicrosoft.com";

        var authUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/"+tenant+"/oauth2/token";
        var RESOURCE_URL = "https://graph.microsoft.com";

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authUri);
        var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId: clientId, clientSecret: clientsecret);
        var result = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(RESOURCE_URL, credential).Result;
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "bearer " + result.AccessToken);

        string content = @"{
 'description': 'description-value',
  'displayName': 'displayName-value',
  'groupTypes': [
    'Unified'
  ],
  'mailEnabled': true,
  'mailNickname': 'mailNickname-value',
  'securityEnabled': false
}";
        var httpContent = new StringContent(content, Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"), "application/json");
        //var response = client.GetAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups").Result;
        var response = client.PostAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups",httpContent).Result;
        Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
```

More detail about Goupr REST API, please refer to [here](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/group).

For the error “InvalidAuthenticationToken” you were request the access token with incorrect resource. To use the Microsoft Graph API, we need to specify the resource with “https://graph.microsoft.com” instead of “https://graph.windows.net”.

In addition, if you want the mailNickName of group is updateable, you can try to submit the feedback from [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).

Comment: Thanks. Now its error free.I have one doubt is it possible to create email alias for a existing email using graph api with same way?

Comment: Is it possible to add more than one  alias names [mailNickName ]  for user email using api ? [Not at the created time instead when ever we want to add more alias name]

Comment: No. The user only have one mailNickName. You can refer to the [document](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_update), the type of this parameter is string instead of collection.

Comment: Can I update the otherMails option when ever i want?

Comment: Which option did you want to update? The [mailNickName] is also not able to update after the user created using the REST.

Comment: my aim is to implement a functionality in which i want to generate alias for email with mail box permission dynamically [suppose 10 alias]and store in db.using graph API and to that email alias i want to send email.I already have a email account that have mail box. if alias for email wont work any work around to obtain this feature using other properties ?

Comment: It seems that your application want to support multiple alias for the mail box. If I understood correct, since the Office 365 doesn't support the multiple alias, you need to handle this business login in the application. For example, you can store the alias relative to the mail box and replace the alias with the mail address before the app send the email.